# Question of Javascript scope within a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

I am (quite obviously) a beginner in javascript. I am attempting to understand why, when using a for loop and calling an event handler ala

http://jsfiddle.net/Yw5Uj/

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
var navLinks = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var contentSections = content.getElementsByTagName('div');


for(i =0; i < contentSections.length; i++) {
    contentSections[i].style.display = 'none';
}

for(i =0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    navLinks[i].onmouseover = function() {
         contentSections[i-1].style.display = 'block'
    }
}
```

I only get the last iteration of the loop. How would I call a function to act on each of the links in the navLinks array as they are moused over?

There are many questions on this, but often times they are a bit too complicated for me to understand.

Comment: The answer is simple: There is no scope in `for` loops ;)

Comment: @FelixKling: Wait, this has been asked before?! :p

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var makeFunction = function(i) {
  return function() { contentSections[i-1].style.display = 'block'; };
};

for(var i =0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    navLinks[i].onmouseover = makeFunction(i);
}
```

What's throwing you off is the lifetime semantics of `i`.  In Javascript there is only one `i` defined for the current function (and without the use of `var` it's likely in the global scope).  So every function assigned to `onmouseover` is using the same `i` variable which has the final value of `navLinks.length`.

My solution works because it uses function scope to create a new `i` for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please don't answer obvious dups; it sets a bad precedent.

Comment: Ummm, `onmouseover` should be a function, your helper function doesn't return a function though.

Comment: I thought the same thing, refreshed, it was already updated :)

Answer (score 0):

[Updated example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw5Uj/10/).

```
function handleMouseOver(i) {
    return function () {
        for (var j = 0; j < navLinks.length; j++) {
            contentSections[j].style.display = 'none';
        }
        contentSections[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}

for(i =0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    navLinks[i].onmouseover = handleMouseOver(i);
}
```